# What method can be used rather of "getBytes()" in salesforce, this method basically changes string to byte

Tags: string, conversion

Below is code snippet from C# which needs to be converted in Apex:

```
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("string");
```

Comment: Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ypWIAQ